# Can't connect to PPTP VPNs in Windows 8.1

Tags: networking, windows-8, vpn, pptp

I have a couple PPTP VPNs which I've set up in Windows 8.1 . 
They were working fine for months and months, able to connect with no issues. 
Then a couple weeks ago they stopped working, and I get a code 720 error.

[image]

As far as I can see, every single post online talking about how to fix this talks about the WAN Miniports in device manager being broken with the little yellow exclamation marks on them.

I've looked in my device manager however, and all my miniports appear to be operating fine, none of them have the exclamation marks on them.

As I said, this worked fine for months, and then just stopped working with no changes to my computer. I've tried over both wired and wireless connections. I've tried updating my NIC drivers. I've checked for Windows updates but there are none.

Any one have any ideas what this could be or where I should look next? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If resetting PPTP and L2TP WAN miniport doesn't fix the problem, the following steps could solve it:

1.Run Control Panel -> System and Security -> Windows Firewall.

2.Click Advanced settings on the left.

3.Choose Inbound Rules.

4.On the right click New Rule....

5.Select Predefined, choose Routing and Remote Access, and click Next.

6.Check all three rules, and click Next.

7.Choose Allow the connection, and click Finish.

8.repeat actions for Secure Socket Tunneling Protocol (in Inbound Rules).

9.repeat actions for Routing and Remote Access (in Outbound Rules).

10.Restart computer, and VPN connection.

Comment: I'll have to give it a try, but this wouldn't seem to jive with the fact that it was working for months and then just stopped. Unless some recent `Windows Update` made changes to the default firewall rules?

Comment: Windows 8.1 firewall rules block VPN connections by default :/

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and solved by doing this.

On the `Security` tab of the properties screen on the VPN connection, select `PPTP` for the type.

Select `Allow these protocols` and select `MS-CHAP v2`.

Optional - Select `Automatically use my Windows Logon name and password (if applicable)`

Best of luck